# Complicated SUM formula

Tags: excel

I'm having a nightmare trying to come up with a formula to solve the following issue. I have two columns 'Record Count' and 'Actual Hours', where record count is greater than 1 I need to sum the data in actual hours. If possible I only want to use one formula and the maximum record count that I can see is 5.

So if you check out the image below, for the rows where the are 5 records I want to see 15.75.

This would be the sum of 1.19, 1.75, 2.31, 3.5 and 7 as these all relate to a single client.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pblu3.png)

Comment: Not sure how you got 15.75, but I'm quite sure you need to use sumif or sumifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to get total time for each clientid. In that case it does not matter whether there is one or more records for the client. Assuming,  clientid is column C and Actual hours column D,  in B2 enter =SUMIF(C:C=C2, D:D). Copy all the way down.

Comment: When entering your suggested formula;


=SUMIF(ClientIDRange,"=FirstClientID",ActualHoursRange)


Everything results in 0. If I remove the quotations and use your format the formula also errors.

Comment: Remove the quotes and also the = before Firstclientid. It should be =SUMIF(ClientIDRange,FirstClientID, ActualHoursRange)

Comment: worked great, thanks. Haven't used SUMIF until today but may find more uses for it in future.

Comment: This solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a task for `SUMIF()`:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">1",B:B)
```

(assuming `A:A` is 'Recoud Count' column and `B:B` is 'Actual Hours')

This will get you the sum of hours where record cound is more than 1.

Comment: I've just attempted that with no joy. Every cell now reports the total of 578.25 which is the total of every record count over 1. Is there anyway to partition this by an ID column which is available?

Comment: Isn't your problem about this? Find a sum of hours where record count is >1.

Comment: He wants the sum of the hours for the maximum value in A, I believe.  So something like `=sumif(A:A,max(A:A),B:B)` . So in this case it would only some the ones with a value of 5 in column A based on the screen shot.

Comment: >1 in the case of the screenshot is the same as `= SUM(B:B)`

Comment: @NHiler1992 update the question with desired result and a better description.

Comment: @Andreas the desired result is the sum of the Actual Hours column for each client.

Question updated to show how I got to 15.75

Comment: @Taosique I do want the sum of the Actual Hours column but if possible I would like this per client. So if client A has 2 records and client B has 5 these should provide different values.

Comment: @NHier1992 that does not change the answer.  You would use SUMIF() still.  Assuming your first column is A and the Customer ID is C: `=sumif(C:C,C2,D:D)`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from second record you can do partial sums. Here B is record count, C is client ID, D is actual hours. For second line (E2):

```
=IF(AND(B2>0,C2=C1),E1+D2,IF(C2>0,D2,0))
```

For A2:

```
=IF(C3=C2,"",E2)
```

It uses two formulas, requires to move whole table one row down and only places one entry against each client. If this is works for you - give it a try.

---

If you don't want to move data you can paste this formula in E2:

```
=IF(ROW(E2)==1,IF(B2>0,D2,IF(C2>0,D2,0)),IF(AND(B2>0,C2=C1),E1+D2,IF(C2>0,D2,0)))
```

If the row is first the rows above are ignored (avoiding nullPointerException). If the row is second or below it works does the comparison to see border of userid.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know the outcome. Thanks

Comment: Slightly confused by the row movement required. Would it be possible to get an example image in your answer?

Comment: @NHier1992 I've edited the answer. Yes, you can avoid moving the table. but the formula doubles it's size.